# Geodesic curvature of sphere parallels

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, geodesic

I want to compute the geodesic curvature of any circle on a sphere (not necessarily a great circle).

$$$$

The geodesic curvature is given by the formula $$\kappa_g=\gamma'' \cdot (\textbf{N}\times \gamma ')$$ or $$\kappa_g=\pm \kappa \sin \psi$$ 
where $\gamma$ is a unit-speed curve of the surface, $\textbf{N}$ is the normal unit of the surface, $\kappa$ is the curvature of $\gamma$ and $\psi$ is the angle between $\textbf{N}$ and the principal normal $n$ of $\gamma$.

$$$$

We consider a circle of radius $r$.

Could you give me some hints how we could calculate the geodesic curvature?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: You can apply a rotation to assume the circle is parallel to the $xy$-plane. You can then easily write down a unit speed parametrization and an expression for $N$ and just do the computation.

Comment: Is the unit-speed parametrization $\gamma (r, \theta )=\left (r\cos \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ), r\sin \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ),\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\right )$ ? Or should be in respect to only one variable? @AlexG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write down parametric equations for the circle. Then you can compute various derivatives and apply the formulae you cited.

Set up a coordinate system that has its origin at the center of the sphere and its positive $z$-axis going through the center of the circle.

Suppose the sphere has radius $a$ and the circle has radius $r$, where $r \le a$. Then the circle lies in the plane $z=h$, where $h = \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}$, and a unit-speed parameterization is
\begin{align}
x &= r \cos(\theta/r) \\
y &= r\sin(\theta/r)  \\
z &= h = \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}
\end{align}
So, we have
$$
\gamma(\theta) = \left(r \cos\frac{\theta}{r}, \;
                        r \sin\frac{\theta}{r}, \; \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}\right)
$$
$$
\gamma'(\theta) = \left(- \sin\frac{\theta}{r}, \;
                           \cos\frac{\theta}{r}, \; 0\right)
$$
$$
\gamma''(\theta) = \left(-\frac{1}{r} \cos\frac{\theta}{r}, \;
                         -\frac{1}{r} \sin\frac{\theta}{r}, \; 0\right)
$$
The surface normal $\mathbf{N}$ at the point $\gamma(\theta)$ is just $\gamma(\theta)/a$, so 
$$
\mathbf{N}(\theta) = \left(\frac{r}{a} \cos\frac{\theta}{r}, \;
                           \frac{r}{a} \sin\frac{\theta}{r}, \; 
                           \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}{a} \right)
$$
Then a straightforward computation shows that
$$
\kappa_g = \gamma'' \cdot (\mathbf{N}\times \gamma ') =
\frac{h}{ra} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}{ra}
$$
The result is actually easier to obtain from the second formula for $\kappa_g$. The vectors $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are shown in the OP's picture, and $\psi$ is the angle between them. The complementary angle ${\pi}- \psi$ lies in  in the triangle with sides $a$, $h$, $r$, which gives us $\sin(\pi - \psi) = \text{opposite}/\text{hypotenuse} = h/a$. Then $\sin\psi = \sin(\pi - \psi) = h/a$. Obviously $\kappa = 1/r$, so 
$$
\kappa_g = \kappa\, \sin\psi = \frac{1}{r}\frac{h}{a} = \frac{h}{ra} =
\frac{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}{ra}
$$

Comment: I haven't understood the part: $$$$ "Then the circle lies in the plane $z=h$, where $h = \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}$" $$$$ Could you explain it further to me? Why does the circle lie in that plane?

Comment: Because of the way we set up the coordinate system, the circle lies in a plane $z= h$, for **some** $h$. Draw a picture and use Pythagoras' theorem, and you'll see where the value of $h$ comes from.

Comment: I added a picture in my initial post... Could you take a look at it? Do you mean it like that?

Comment: I haven't really understood how we use Pythagoeas to get $h$. Could you explain it furher to me?

Comment: At which triangle do we apply Pythagoras' theorem?

Comment: I changed now the picture... Is the hypotenuse the green line?

Comment: Ok... So, do we take as the unit-speed curve of the surface, $\gamma (r, \theta )=\left (r\cos \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ), r\sin \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ),\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\right )$ ?

Comment: Or should $\gamma$ be in respect only to one variable? What is $\gamma ''$ ? In respect to which variable do we differentiate?

Comment: I see... So, we have the following: $$\gamma (\theta )=\left (r\cos \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ), r\sin \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ),\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\right ) \\ \gamma ' (\theta )=\left (-\sin \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ), \cos \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ),0\right ) \\ \gamma '' (\theta )=\left (-\frac{1}{r}\cos \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ), -\frac{1}{r}\sin \left (\frac{\theta}{r}\right ),0\right )$$

Comment: How can we compute the unit normal $N$ ? 
When $\sigma$ is a surface patch, the formula is $N=\frac{\sigma_u\times\sigma_v}{\|\sigma_u\times\sigma_v\|}$, right? But how is it in this case?

Comment: Yes, but on a sphere, getting the surface normal is easy without any fancy formulae. The unit normal at the point $\mathbf{x} = (x,y,z)$ is just the vector $\mathbf{x} / \| \mathbf{x} \|$

Comment: So, do we use as the unit normal the vector $N=\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ ?

Comment: So, doing the calculations we get $$\kappa_g=\gamma'' \cdot (\textbf{N}\times \gamma ')=\frac{z}{r\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$ or not?

Comment: Since the radius of the sphere is $a$, we have that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=a$, right? So $$\kappa_g=\gamma'' \cdot (\textbf{N}\times \gamma ')=\frac{z}{ra}$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Ok... Good night!! :-)

Comment: I get $\kappa_g = \frac{h}{ra}$. Remember that $z=h$ everywhere on the circle.

Comment: The calculations are easier if you use the second formula. From the picture, it's clear that $\sin\psi = h/a$, and obviously $\kappa = 1/r$, so you're done.

Comment: How did you find that $\sin \psi =\frac{h}{a}$ ? $\psi$ is the angle between $N$ and the principal normal $n$ of $\gamma$. Is $n$ parallel to the $z$-axis?

Comment: I changed the picture of my initial post... Could you take a look at it? $n$ is on the plane $z=\text{constant}$, right? Can $N$ not be there?

Comment: The tan of angle  $ \lambda $ or $ \psi$  between parallel circle normal and sphere surface normal is  ratio of curvatures. Can you mark $ n,N?$

Comment: Where should I mark them? What do you mean? @Narasimham

Comment: My errror, I just see $n,N$  are already marked in your diagram. Taking $a$  radius vector instead of unit speed we have $ N =( r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, \sqrt{a^2-r^2}) ; $ and, $ n = ( r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, 0 ) ; $  and $  \tan(n,N) = z/r. $

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For a more intrinsic perspective, parametrize the sphere as $$\varphi(u,v)=(\sin(u)\cos(v),\sin(u)\sin(v),\cos(u)),$$

so that the coefficients of the first fundamental for are $E=1$, $F=0$ and $G=\sin^2(u)$. Then a lattitude circle on the sphere is a $v$-curve associated with this parametrization, and thus may be parametrized as $$\alpha_v(t)=\varphi(u_0,t)=(\sin(u_0)\cos(t),\sin(u_0)\sin(t),\cos(u_0)),$$ 
with $0<u_0<\pi$. Its arclength parametrization is then given by $$\beta(s)=\varphi\left(u_0,\frac{s}{\sin(u_0)}\right).$$
Now when $F=0$ there is a nice formula for the geodesic curvature $\kappa_g$ of an arclength parametrized curve of the form $\varphi(u(s),v(s))$ (for a general parametrization $\varphi$ of a regular surface), namely, $$\kappa_g=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}(G_uv'-E_vu')+\theta',$$ where $\theta$ is the angle from $\varphi_u$ to the velocity vector of the curve, where $\varphi_u=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\varphi$. In our case, the velocity vector $\beta'(s)$ is precisely $\varphi_v=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\varphi$, which is always orthogonal to $\varphi_u$ since $F=0$, thus $\theta'=0$. Moreover, we have $u'=0$, $v'=1/\sin{u_0}$ and $G_u=2\sin(u_0)\cos(u_0)$, thus $$\kappa_g=\cot(u_0).$$

Answer (score 3):

The derivation of geodesic curvature is correct. I shall attempt putting all so far into one perspective.

Total curvature has two orthogonal components, normal and geodesic: $ k_n, k_g. $

Normal/ geodesic  curvatures are :  $k_n = 1/ a,  k_g = 1/ R_g, $ Latitude $ \lambda ( \psi) = \tan^{-1} \dfrac{k_g}{k_n}. $

Geodesic curvature for any surface of revolution is the reciprocal of tangent length up to axis of symmetry as shown.

[image: GeodCurvSphereParallels]