# Prove that a simple closed curve on a sphere bisects the sphere into 2 parts of equal area.

Tags: differential-geometry

So i am given a normal curve that is simple and closed and that is on the 2-sphere. I need to prove that this curve bisects the sphere into 2 parts of equal area 2pi. I know I need to use the Gauss Bonnet Theorem. And so, i need to somehow prove that the integral of the geodesic curvature with respect to the arc length element is 0. But how do i go about doing this??

Could someone also give me an intuitive picture of what we are trying to do, in order to prove this!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "normal" curve? A small circle obviously does not partition the sphere into two parts of equal area.

Comment: I am given a closed space curve on an interval [a,b] to R^3 and for this, if we take the Frenet Frame, the Normal curve N:[a,b] to S^2 in R^3 is a simple,closed curve and this has to be proven to bisect the sphere into 2 halves of equal area using Gauss Bonnet Theorem.

Comment: Very good. Now it is an interesting problem. Please insert these explanations into the question.

Comment: Sorry!!!! I should have!!  I understand that we play around with the geodesic curvature but i am missing intuition! Its a very intersting conclusion,indeed! So would like to understand this well! So any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It seems plausible that one should be able to compute with the formula for geodesic curvature given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590579/geodesic-curvature-of-sphere-parallels along with the Frenet-Serret formulas.