# Geodesic curvature of any circle on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, curvature, geodesic

Assume a sphere of radius $r$. Consider that one hexagon and one square cut the sphere as shown in the attached figure. One circle inscribed within the hexagon with given radius $r_1$ and one circle inscribed within the square with given radius $r_2$, are formed. The two circles are tangent. The centers of these circles are $O_1, O_2$, respectively. Also, assume that the cartesian coordinates of all points $A, B, C, O_1, O_2, O$ are known. The arc lengths $s_1, s_2$ with respect to $O_1, O_2$ are also known.

We are interested in calculating the geodesic curvature of the two blue circular arcs with respect to the center $O$ of the sphere.

Any help/tip would be useful.

**EDIT:** This a kind of a generalization of the question presented in [Geodesic curvature of sphere parallels](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590579/geodesic-curvature-of-sphere-parallels) . In our case, the circles are *not* necessarily in parallel with a great circle.

[image: small arcs on the surface of a sphere]

Comment: $$\kappa_i=\dfrac1{r_i}.$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is it so? I want to apply Gauss-Bonnet theorem to find a part of the surface area of this sphere and I want to known if the curvatures of the arcs need to be represented with respect to the center $O$ of the sphere or it is just $1/r_i$ in each case, as you mentioned? Thank you.

Comment: The curvature of a circle is the inverse of its radius.

Comment: Well, the answer is not always. Please refer to the following link, for example.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590579/geodesic-curvature-of-sphere-parallels

Comment: Sorry, I missed *geodesic* curvature.