# How can one calculate the geodesic curvature of arbitrary arcs on a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, curvature, geodesic

Consider that one regular hexagon and one square cut a sphere of radius $r$ as shown in the attached figure. A circular arc of length $s_1$ and a circular arc of length $s_2$ are formed (blue arcs). The arc $AB$ is a part of a small circle centered at a given point $O_1$, while the arc $AC$ is an arbitrary arc of a circle centered at the point $O_2$.

Assuming that the coordinates of the points $A, B, C$ with respect to a common coordinate system are known, how can we compute the geodesic curvature of these circular arcs?

Any tip/help would be useful.

**My approach:** Given the formula presented in [Geodesic curvature of sphere parallels](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590579/geodesic-curvature-of-sphere-parallels), the small circle geodesic curvature is given by $\kappa_g = 
\frac{\sqrt{r^2 - r_1^2}}{rr_1}$, where $r_1$ denotes the radius of the small circle centered at $O_1$.

Similarly, how can we compute $\kappa_g$ for the other arbitrary circular arc?

[image: Arbitrary arcs formed on the surface of a sphere]

Answer (score 1):

That seems an exceedingly cumbersome formula and I haven't checked it. It is a standard formula (which can be checked with a tiny bit of trig, or by using the formula $\kappa_g = \pm\sqrt{\kappa^2-\kappa_n^2}$) that a geodesic circle of radius $R$ on a sphere of radius $r$ has $\kappa_g = \dfrac1r\cot R$. Does this help you? (Your circular arcs are arcs of geodesic circles centered at $O_1$ and $O_2$.)

Comment: I actually want to apply Gauss-Baunnet Theorem to an area of the sphere, so I suppose I need to express all geodesic curvatures of the arcs with respect to a common coordinate system (e.g. with z-axis passing through $O_1$)

Comment: That makes no sense. The geodesic curvature doesn't depend on any coordinate system.